# How many milligrams of caffeine are in a fresh coffee bean?

Tags: caffeine, beans

how much caffeine in a raw coffee bean? As in, raw, freshly picked, just remove hard outer shell and eat the rest.

Answer (score 2):

There are [about 6 mg](https://coffee-channel.com/much-caffeine-coffee-bean/) of caffeine in one coffee bean. Darker roasts may have 10-15% less.

> ...dark roasts have a stronger taste, but the roasting procedure they experience decreases their caffeine content by 10 to 15 percent. If you prefer dark roasted beans, congratulations! They basically contain 15% to 20% less caffeine than the lightly roasted ones.

In the answers to this [Question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/304/is-it-possible-to-feel-any-effects-after-chewing-one-coffee-bean) there is plenty of information about this subject.

Comment: Its my understanding that the roasting process removes a lot of the caffeine - you are referring to roasted beans

Comment: you are right @swinters I updated my answer to clarify this point (+ change broken links for new ones...)
cheers